# Typescript import types

Tags: typescript

I'm not able to find out a good description of tpescript imports.

What are the difference between this import types?

- `import { Country } from '../../models/country.model.ts';`
  This seems normal. You import an exported class/interface of a project ts file
- `import * as mapsData from 'blablabla/world.js';`
  In this case am I referenceing a js file directly? Is this possible? Are there some preconditions? This works without using the allowJs flag.
- `import something from 'path'`
  Why is this case I'm not using brackets?

Comment: you don't need incoude file extensions. The trick is to include `allowJS` in **tsconfig.json** file. The default option is `false`. Refer to: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: `import something from 'path'` mean this **module** has `default export.` Without `'./path'`, you refer to module rather than local files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain using examples

Let's assume we have 2 files, `exp.ts` and `imp.ts`.

```
// exp.ts
export const A = 1;
export default 2;
```

---

```
// imp.ts
import {A} from "./exp";
import * as B from "./exp";
import C from "./exp";

console.log(A)
console.log(B)
console.log(C)
```

Executing `imp.ts` will give result

```
1
{ A: 1, default: 2 }
2
```

---

Why?

`import {A} from "./exp";` - imports named element as a variable

`import * as B from "./exp";` - imports all exported elements and saves them to a variable

`import C from "./exp";` - imports `default` export and saves it to a variable, this is equivalent of `import {default as C} from "./exp";`